# C Array copying

Tags: c, arrays, copy, malloc

I made myself an array:

```
double* input_array_pointer;
input_array_pointer = (double*)malloc(input_array_size * sizeof(double));

fill_array(input_array);
```

Now I have array full of doubles.

I need to make output array which need to be copy of input array but all I got myself is pointer pointing to input array.
(Therefore, all the work I make on output array—such as changing certain numbers— is being applied to input array.)

Here's how I do it which is WRONG:

```
double* output_array_pointer;
    output_array_pointer = (double*)malloc(array_size * sizeof(double))/*memory allocation using malloc*/

memcpy(output_array_pointer, input_array_pointer, (sizeof(input_array_pointer))+1);
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Right. `sizeof` won't help you here, you will need to keep track of the array length yourself.

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer returns the size of the pointer itself, not whatever data it might point to.

Comment: if the size is not that big you could take your array on the stack, then sizeof would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` operator only "works" on arrays that are statically declared (eg: `double my_array[10]`).  Otherwise, `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer, which is not what you want.

To properly copy a dynamically allocated array, you need to know the size of that array.  In your case, that's `input_array_size`:

```
memcpy(output_array_pointer, input_array_pointer, input_array_size * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! now i have problem of my program crashing when i try to take part of the array, then deepcopy using memcpy that part of aray to another while moving trough starting point of arrays via for cycle, where can be problem of crashing?